# Inserting an Event in Google Calendar with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a Google Calendar event using the code below:

```
  Sub UpdateCalendar()
    Dim CalendarEvent As New Data.Event
    Dim StartDateTime As New Data.EventDateTime
    Dim A As Date
    A = "15-OCT-2016 12:00"
    StartDateTime.DateTime = A
    Dim b As Date
    b = A.AddDays(2)
    Dim EndDateTime As New Data.EventDateTime
    EndDateTime.DateTime = b
    CalendarEvent.Start = StartDateTime
    CalendarEvent.End = EndDateTime
    CalendarEvent.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    CalendarEvent.Description = "Test"
    service.Events.Insert(CalendarEvent, "primary").Execute()
  End Sub
```

But I am getting the following error in the last line:

```
Invalid resource id value. [400]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The suggested "duplicate" does not address the problem since it is for Java and it suggests switching the parameters, which did not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set event id on google calendar java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304722/set-event-id-on-google-calendar-java)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently commenting the following line solved the problem:

```
CalendarEvent.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
```