# google calendar api Error 400 - Invalid resource id value

Tags: symfony, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to insert events in Google calendar through the API using a Symfony command (batch).

When I insert an event with an ID like "event01487", it throws me the following errors : "code": 400, "message": "Invalid resource id value."

This id is unique as no events have been inserted - it didn't even insert it once. The id seems to fit the Google requirements...

Do you have any idea why I got this ?

```
foreach($bookingsToSync as $booking){
     $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
     $event->setId($booking['id']);
     $event->setSummary($booking['title']);
     $event->setDescription($booking['description']);

     $start = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
     $start->setDateTime($booking['startDate']->format(DateTime::ATOM));
     $event->setStart($start);
     $end = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
     $end->setDateTime($booking['endDate']->format(DateTime::ATOM));
     $event->setEnd($end);

     $output->writeln($event->getId());

     $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set event id on google calendar java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304722/set-event-id-on-google-calendar-java)

Comment: Nope it's not. the issue is the same but I already did what the accepted answer said

Comment: @RomHill These little gremlins are quick to dismiss questions without actually checking. Fishing for points.

Answer (score 6):

You have to follow the guidelines defined here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Basically, the id has to be between 5 and 1024 characters and be composed from characters in this alphabet : 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv

Comment: JJP, how does your answer help? The ID in question "event01487" conforms to these guidelines and yet there is an error. I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I agree; I don't see how this helps with the standard type failures. I am surprised to see that wxyz are not allowed; I didn't realize that before. Could explain *some* of the issues I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your id as base32

```
$encoded = bin2hex( $booking['id'] );
```

To Decode

```
$decoded = hex2bin( $encoded );
```